# Elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}(T)$ receiving only constant maps from modular curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory

Is there an elliptic curve $E/\mathbb{Q}(T)$ such that any map $X_1(N)\to E$ for any $N>0$ is constant?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: If you had such a non constant map, you would get a uniformization of every fiber of E/Q(T), right?

Comment: @WillSawin I have tried the elliptic curves base changed from $\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Any elliptic curve which is not base-changed from $\mathbb Q$ will do the trick.

If there were such a nonconstant map, there would be a surjection from the Jacobian of the modular curve to the elliptic curve. There are many ways to rule this out.

One way is to look at $\ell$-adic Tate module of the elliptic curves. It's easy to check that the action of $\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb Q(T))$ on it does not factor through $\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb Q)$, at least in an explicit example like $y^2 = x^3-T$ where we can check that the Galois action on the $2$-torsion points does not so factor. It fullows that the Tate module does not admit any surjection from a representation whose Galois action does factor through $\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb Q)$, such as the Jacobian of a modular curve.

Comment: Is there some notion of modular curve over $\mathbb{Q}(T)$ that is not a constant curve?

Comment: @virkkunen I don't think so.